# How to get data from 3 tables with eager loading in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a table relationship like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/MptsW.jpg

This problem about eager loading features Laravel framework

My code for eager loading like this :

```
$schedules = Schedule::whereHas(
    'mahasiswa',
    function($mahasiswa) use ($start, $limit, $order, $dir, $search) {
        $mahasiswa->whereHas(
            'document_thesises',
            function($documentThesis) use ($start, $limit, $order, $dir, $search) {
                $documentThesis->where('npm', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                    ->orWhere('name', 'LIKE', "%$search%")
                    ->offset($start)
                    ->limit($limit)
                    ->orderBy($order, $dir);
        });
    }
)->get();
```

for the model from the table above the code is like this: 
Mahasiswa Model :

```
public function document_thesises()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DocumentThesis::class, 'id', 'document_thesis_id');
}
```

DocumentThesis Model :

```
public function mahasiswa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Mahasiswa::class);
}
```

Schedule Model :

```
public function mahasiswa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Mahasiswa::class, 'mahasiswa_id', 'id');
}
```

I hope the results can display all data from the `schedule` table based on the `document_thesis` table. But, I got error like this :

```
exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
file: "/mnt/d/www/eta/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php"
line: 664
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'mahasiswas.document_thesis_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `schedules` where exists (select * from `mahasiswas` where `schedules`.`mahasiswa_id` = `mahasiswas`.`id` and exists (select * from `document_thesises` where `mahasiswas`.`document_thesis_id` = `document_thesises`.`id` order by `id` asc limit 10 offset 0) and `mahasiswas`.`deleted_at` is null))"
trace: [,…]
```

Answer (score 0):

change document_thesises function in Mahasiswa Model to

```
public function document_thesises()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(DocumentThesis::class, 'document_thesis_id','id');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is throwing this exception is that the relation of `Mahasiswa@document_thesises` is incorrect. As we can see the relation that is needed is a one-to-many. In Laravel terms the `HasMany` relationship should be used.

Currently your code suggests it is a `BelongsTo` relationship, which needs a local foreign key of the related model. The query is trying to join the related models on the `mahasiswas.document_thesis_id` which is not there.

Changing the relation method to `hasMany` should do the trick.

```
// Mahasiswa model
public function document_thesises()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DocumentThesis::class);
}

// DocumentThesis model
public function mahasiswa()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Mahasiswa::class);
}
```